# How to promote a Dracaena to branch

Tags: houseplants, indoors, dracaena

I have a Dracaena cutting that has taken very well and there is good upwards growth but it is just a single stem at the moment. Is there any way to promote braching is this type of plant?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to let it branch is to cut off the top. Or try to use branching hormones, like [BAP](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47075/can-a-cactus-be-encouraged-to-branch-out/47078#47078), and put it on a sleeping eye.